# c++ converting from char to string?

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, data-conversion

Im having some issues in converting a char value of a vector to a string.
I have a globaly declared vector as such.

```
std::vector<Musician> aMusician;
```

that stores values from a file read into a struct

```
struct Musician {
char code;
int impact;
};
```

code is a single char of values either A,B,C,D,E,F,G or H

I have a function that takes in a string value and checks if this string value contains any of the possiblle codes(example string x = ABCD, it would contain the codes A B C and D). A standard string target is used to store the char after conversion using a stringstream.

its used like so

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string target;

 for (Musician musc : aMusician)
    {
      ss << musc.code;
      ss >> target;

if (target.find(variable1.at(0)) != std::string::npos) {
//code
}
 
}
```

However they do not match. Target is only storing A where as the vector contains A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H. Or in other words Target is only storing the first code.

Below is a test output of when i print both target and the vector values

```
vector: A
target: A
vector: B
target: A(should be B)
vector: C
target: A (should be C.....etc)
vector: D
target: A
vector: E
target: A
vector: F
target: A
vector: G
target: A
vector: H
```

Below are example records of the files being and used and how they match

file contains code(in this case A)

```
A:Lead singer:2:10:3.
B:Backing singer:5:2:2.
C:Guitarist:3:6:2.
D:Singing guitarist:2:8:3.
```

file containing word to match(for exmaple in this case A matches with A1 and band1)

```
band1:A1B3C4.
band2:A4B1C5D1E1H5
```

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Have you tried flushing `ss` to `target` only once, after the loop?

Comment: @bipll howw would i go aboout that?

Comment: @DickChang put the closing brace right after `ss << musc.code;`?

Comment: If you want to make `target` equal to `musc.code`, just say so: `target = musc.code;` Your games with `stringstream` don't make much sense. Further, it's unclear why you need `target` variable at all - why not simply `if (musc.code == variable1.at(0)) ...` ?